# Como somar valores em uma coluna da tabela a cada registro digitado

Tags: php

Preciso somar nas colunas `total_débitos` e `total_créditos` da tabela do banco de dados, o valor do lançamento de cada um dos registros digitados. Tenho o seguinte código:

Na tabela:

```
saldo_anterior   total_débitos   total_créditos   saldo_atual
```

Meu código:

```
<tr>
<td align="right">
    <strong>Valor do Lançamento R$:</strong>
</td>
<td>
    <input name="valor_lancto" type="text" id="valor_lancto" size="14" 
     maxlength="20"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

A cada lançamento feito, somar na coluna `total_débitos` ou na coluna `total_créditos`, conforme o tipo do lançamento (se [D] débito ou [C] crédito)

Comment: Sem saber o seu código fica dificil entender, consegue postar o bloco de código aqui pra gente?

Comment: Bem-vindo, antes de tudo leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/

Comment: Para somar os valores de uma coluna do banco de dados você pode usar `select sum(coluna) from tabela`, mais que isso fica difícil ajudar sem mais informações

Comment: Seja muito bem vindo à comunidade SOpt Joaquim, considere dar uma olhada em [Como Perguntar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Em relação à sua dúvida, você pode **fornecer mais informações sobre o seu código?** **Você utiliza algum banco de dados ?** **Qual?**

Comment: Na sua tabela (sem nome) não deveria ter um **tipo de lançamento** ? Ou tem algum relacionamento com outra tabela ?